# Can the standard math functions handle infinity correctly?

Tags: c++, c, math, floating-point

```
int main() {
    double inf = INFINITY;
    double pi = acos(-1.0);
    printf("[1]: %f %f\n", atan(inf) / pi, atan(-inf) / pi);
    printf("[2]: %f %f\n", tan(inf) / pi, tan(-inf) / pi);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
[1]: 0.500000 -0.500000
[2]: -nan -nan
```

Is such behaviour defined by the standard? Is `[2]` undefined behaviour? unspecified?

I want to be sure at least `[1]` is a guaranteed result.

Comment: You ask “Is such behaviour defined by the standard?” and you tag your question C **and** C++? Really? Why not read “the” standard for yourself, at least you'll pick the one you mean?

Comment: Read : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan

Comment: For not even bothering to read the documentation for the functions you use, -1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq The math functions are one of the parts where it could be reasonable to tag it for both languages. The C++ standard doesn't say anything about them, it references all these functions from the C standard and only specifies additional overloads that shall behave the same way as the C version.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Well, the math functions are both in the C and C++ standard library, so I thought they are defined identical between the two languages.

Comment: @xiver77 there are slight but important differences between C++ and C in many parts, `<cmath>`/`<math.h>` are one of the few places that are pretty much identical though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I was just too confident that I know what `atan` is in terms of mathematics and didn't even think of reading the documentation. I thought such detail is about how the language defines floating points.

Comment: @xiver77: And that's why we read the documentation. To allay our false assumptions before bothering others!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are well defined behaviour.
Quoting from http://en.cppreference.com

- tan

  > If the argument is ±0, it is returned unmodified.
  >       If the argument is ±∞, NaN is returned and FE_INVALID is raised.
  >       If the argument is NaN, NaN is returned.
- atan

  > If the argument is ±0, it is returned unmodified.
  >       If the argument is +∞, +π/2 is returned.
  >       If the argument is -∞, -π/2 is returned.
  >       If the argument is NaN, NaN is returned.